# Object Browser in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I can't for the life of me find the object browser on Visual Studio for Mac.

At first I thought it was under tools --> Assembly Browser, but all I see is a blank page.

Anyone else run in to this issue and solve it?

I am running: Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac (Version 17.4.3 (build 21))[image]

Comment: There isn’t one on one feature parity, so get used to missing features.

Comment: From your screenshot it does not look like it is showing the list on the left hand side. Is there a separator you can drag to the right? I see a list of assemblies when a solution is opened in Visual Studio for Mac 17.4. The IDE log (Help - Open Visual Studio Log) may have some error information related to the assembly browser.

Comment: Hi @MattWard - thanks for replying! I'm really sorry but I don't know what you mean by separator. I just have a flashing cursor on an empty page. I've tried dragging the program class, other classes and the solution file in to the window, but nothing happens.

Comment: There should be a vertical separator (thin grey line) in the Assembly Viewer window which I do not see in your screenshot. It might be all the way over to the left hiding the list of assemblies? https://i.stack.imgur.com/NepYy.png

Comment: No I definitely don't have a vertical separator. This is so frustrating. Really appreciate your help @MattWard.